# What's different between FlutterError.onError and runZonedGuarded.onError?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

Please explain to me what is the difference between them. Can they be used together or only separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FlutterError.onError is a method that allows you to hook into the Flutter framework's error-handling mechanism, so you can receive callbacks when an error occurs during the build, layout, or painting phases.

runZonedGuarded is a utility function that allows you to run a block of code in a new zone with a custom error handler. The onError parameter is the error handler that will be called if an error occurs within the zone.

So, in summary:

- FlutterError.onError is specific to the Flutter framework and is used
  to handle errors during the build, layout, and painting phases.
- runZonedGuarded.onError is more general and allows you to run a block
  of code in a new zone with a custom error handler, which can be used
  for a wider range of error-handling needs.

Yes, FlutterError.onError and runZonedGuarded.onError can be used together in a Flutter application.

For example, you can use FlutterError.onError to handle errors that occur during the build, layout, or painting phases, and use runZonedGuarded.onError to handle errors that occur within a specific block of code.

In this way, you can have multiple error handlers in your Flutter application to handle different types of errors in different parts of the code.